# Adding Items to List and Iterator Problems

Tags: c++, iterator, breadth-first-search

Was trying to implement a breadth-first-search.

The graph I was testing on is the following 4<-2<-1->3 (meaning 1 is the root, 1 connects to 2, 2 connects to 4. 3 only connects to 1).

I do not understand why when iter_queue points to 2, the whole loop that follows is skipped.

Any hints? Thank you.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <list>


enum state{white=1, grey, black};

struct node
{
    int index;
    int state = white;
    std::list<node> neighbors;
};


bool search(node n1, node n2) 
{
    using namespace std;
    std::list<node> queue;
    queue.push_back(n1);

    auto iter_queue = queue.begin();

    while(iter_queue!=queue.end())
    {

        auto iter1=iter_queue->neighbors.begin();


        while(iter1!=iter_queue->neighbors.end())
        {

            if(iter1->index == n2.index)
            {
                return true;
            } else if(iter1->state!=black)
            {
                if(iter1->state==white){
                    iter1->state=grey;

                    queue.push_back(*iter1);
                }
            }
            ++iter1;
        }
        iter_queue->state = black;
        queue.pop_front();
        iter_queue=queue.begin();
    }
return false;
```

}

Comment: good way to find out is to start using debugger.

Comment: @Satish. Thank you. I did use the debugger, that's how I found out that the loop didn't start as was expected to.

Comment: A node does not *contain* copies of its neighbours. You want reference semantics here.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks. I changed the input to node & n1 and node & n2 but still doesn't work. Any hints?

Comment: In the neighbours list you need to manage **pointers** to neighbour nodes, not **copies** of these nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a list in your struct containing copies of each child node. You need to be using pointers. Try using a current node pointer to hop over each child node:

`Node* currNode;
std::list<node*> neighbors;`